# Code to test download and upload Internet SpeedTest in android

Tags: android

I am in a need to test the speed of Internet through android code for both upload & download. Any one can please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You start a timer, you download a file which you know the size, when the file is downloaded you stop the timer and you get the speed! You start again for the upload